How can I support LERC using the flag GDAL_USE_LERC_INTERNAL for versions > 3.3.0?
I am currently trying to build GDAL 3.8.3 using conan. The GDAL documentation states, LERC and LERC_DEFLATE are available only when using internal libtiff for GDAL < 3.3.0. Since GDAL 3.3.0, LERC compression is also available when building GDAL against external libtiff >= 4.3.0, built itself against https://github.com/esri/lerc
I am interpreting the wording "also available" as it's still available to use the previous approach for versions > 3.3.0, as in, it's just an additional option. This is a requirement for me because I am using conan to configure my project. Unforunately, building libtiff with LERC is not supported at the moment. However, in the GDAL recipe I have set both
        tc.variables["GDAL_USE_LERC"] = self.options.with_lerc
        tc.variables["GDAL_USE_LERC_INTERNAL"] = True

of the variables GDAL_USE_LERC and GDAL_USE_LERC_INTERNAL to True. It seems that it should be supported as the directory that the CMake imports in version 3.8.3. still exists.
However, when trying to import a LERC formatted image I still receive the error,
output_LERC_DEFLATE.tif: Cannot open TIFF file due to missing codec LERC.
when attempting to import LERC or LERC_DEFLATE formatted file. Is their an additional step I could be missing?

Maybe GDAL_USE_LERC cannot be true if GDAL_USE_LERC_INTERNAL is true.

I ended up editing the conanfile for libtiff for implementing the TODO
